# Drupal7 format_date

Tags: drupal

Somebody could help me to how to change string date with format_date function.
Here is my code`$datesql = format_date("2014-04-02 11:11:31", 'custom', 'Y-m-d');
    drupal_set_message(t('date '.$datesql));`

I suppose drupal to show this message "date 2014-04-02", but drupal just show the message "date", not $datesql. What is wrong in my code.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Function "format_date" expects first parameter to be a timestamp, not a string. Try to wrap this first parameter with "strtotime" function and you will get a better result.

PS: do not include a variable in the first parameter of the "t" function. This could result in a lot of translatable strings. Pass it in the second parameter with "@myvar" as key. Check the "t" function documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   $date = new DateTime('2014-04-02 11:11:31');
   $da =  $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   drupal_set_message('date '.$da,'status');
```

format_date() is use a covert a date in drupal created date not a convert a custom date

```
  format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'Y-m-d');
```